# How do I pass a vector as a command line variable?

Tags: r

I have an R script named `script.r`:

```
someVector <- theCommandLineArgument
```

How do I pass `c("some","vector")` to `theCommandLineArgument` via command line R?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `??"command line"`?

Answer (score 0):

Content of `script.r`:

```
input <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

print (paste("Sum of arguments = ", sum(as.numeric(input[1:3]))))
print(input[4:5])
```

Terminal:

```
Rscript script.R 1 2 3 Hello World
```

Output:

```
[1] "Sum of arguments =  6"
[1] "Hello" "World"
```